# How to handle access denied exception using Websocket and Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

I am using spring security along with Websocket, I have the following method,

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_CREATE_USER')")
@MessageMapping("/cashDeposit")
public void cashDeposit(CashDepositRequest cashDepositRequest) {
```

And I have websocket security configuration. Now the problem is, when access is denied, it is throwing an exception,

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
```

And I searched through Stackoverflow and I found most of the questions are related to Servlets (HTTPServletRequest/Response) and not to Websocket.

Please let me know, how to handle AccessDeniedException for websocket and how to send a websocket message back to the user saying 403 forbidden.

### UPDATE

My security config

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends          
AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {

    messages.simpMessageDestMatchers("/topic/**").permitAll()
            .anyMessage().authenticated();
}
@Override
protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    //disable CSRF for websockets for now...
    return true;
}
}
```

My security config for rest services,

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http    .csrf().disable()
            .headers().addHeaderWriter( new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                    XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN)).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**.css").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "DELETE"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(true)
                .maximumSessions(1);

}
```

Comment: @shazin this is my security config

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue and literally nothing is working for me. The `@MessageExceptionHandler` isn't working for me, it's still just send the stack trace to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
@MessageExceptionHandler
@SendToUser(destinations="/queue/errors", broadcast=false)
public ApplicationError handleException(AccessDeniedException exception) {
    // ...
    return appError;
}
```

source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/user-destination.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to observe the exception in a `ChannelInterceptor`, e.g.:

```java
class MyInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterSendCompletion(@Nonnull Message<?> message, @Nonnull MessageChannel channel, boolean sent, Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
           //.. process
        }
    }
}
```

See the implementation from `AbstractMessageChannel`, you may want to put it at top of the chain.